# Based on Latitude longitude , identify residential or business

Tags: api, google-maps, c#-4.0, maps, latitude-longitude

Is there any way to identify if an address is Business or residential based on Latitude and longitude , any API .

Please note that I don't want to look at that map, I have 1000 latitude/longitude combination ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply: no.

At the very least, assuming the centre of every building had a lat/lon associated with it, it would require someone to store all this data.  I guess Google is starting to get there, but consider how few businesses are actually listed in Google maps (does the maps API have the business info that is displayed on the maps?). Then, would you assume that everything **not** listed is residential? Or would you expect all these to be listed discretely too? What about lat/lon that were neither (roads / countryside / state-owned buildings), and those mixed-use buildings (very common in cities) where you might get businesses and flats in the same building.  But even then, you'd need to know the size of **every** building so that every lat/lon passed to the API mapped to the correct building.

I'm pretty sure you'll be waiting a **long** time for anything that comes close to what you're after

## Update 31/03/2010

https://www.geomni.co.uk/ukbuildings does now seem to have this info. It's not cheap, but you might have (some) free access if you're an academic user.

Comment: I think even Google would struggle to create it.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is a standard service.

Further your question is not a yes/no question. It's more a value between 0 - 100%. (or better 0 - 1)
So you better want to calculate the business factor of a coordinate.
This can be done, the question is if you have access to the data:

You could query all companies within a radius, lets say 500m of a coordinate.
Then you count the number of companies returned.
Do some representaive queries in new york city, some european cities, etc,
Then you get a  typical business factor. With that you can compare (by division).

So finally you need a query to get all companies withing a radius (or square) around  a coordinate. Look at Google API if there is a company attribute for the geo coder / reverse coder query.